# htaccess RewriteRule for base URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this code for get path from base url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?short=$1
```

If i request `yourname.com/a81s2`, `short` variable passed `a81s2` value

Now if i want use `yourname.com/webservice/` OR `yourname.com/` for another request work like short url. i want if my url is `/webservice/` `RewriteRule` not work for it